# Why is Facebook as an OpenID provider missing from Data Explorer login?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Why is Facebook as an OpenID provider missing from [Data Explorer login](https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login?returnurl=/stackoverflow/queries)?

Comment: Facebook isn't actually an OpenID provider - they use some other crazy system, because Facebook.

Comment: Why only for data.stackexchange and not for other SE sites?

Comment: The Data Explorer is actually more-or-less a separate project. SE can talk to Facebook's crazy system; the Data Explorer obviously doesn't bother.

Comment: @michaelb958 They use [OAuth](http://oauth.net).